# Qt - QGraphicsItem itemChange method not triggering when item is moved

Tags: c++, qt

I am making a custom QGraphicsItem, that needs to snap to a grid. I started off with Qt documentation where they suggest you to use the **itemChange** method together with **ItemPositionChange**. But in my case the method is called couple of times when Item is created, but nothing is called when i move the gameobject..

sceneobject.h

```
#ifndef SCENEOBJECT_H
#define SCENEOBJECT_H

#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QPen>
#include <QBrush>
#include <QPainter>

class SceneObject : public QGraphicsItem
{
private:
    QRect rect;
    QPen pen;
    QBrush brush;
public:
    SceneObject(int width, int height, QPen pen, QBrush brush);
    QRectF boundingRect() const;

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
protected:
    QVariant itemChange(QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value);
};

#endif // SCENEOBJECT_H
```

sceneobject.cpp

```
#include "sceneobject.h"
#include "qgraphicssceneevent.h"
#include "globals.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <math.h>

SceneObject::SceneObject(int width, int height, QPen pen, QBrush brush)
{
    this->rect = QRect(0, 0, width, height);
    this->pen = pen;
    this->brush = brush;
    this->setFlag(GraphicsItemFlag::ItemIsMovable);
}

QRectF SceneObject::boundingRect() const {
    return QRectF(this->rect);
}

void SceneObject::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) {
    painter->setPen(this->pen);
    painter->setBrush(this->brush);
    painter->drawRect(this->rect);
}

QVariant SceneObject::itemChange(QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value) {
    qDebug() << "Something happened, " << "Value: " << value;
    if (change == ItemPositionChange) {
        qDebug() << "Item was moved, " << "Value: " << value;
        int CELL_SIZE = Globals::CELL_SIZE;
        int x = floor(this->x() / CELL_SIZE) * CELL_SIZE;
        int y = floor(this->y() / CELL_SIZE) * CELL_SIZE;
        return QPointF(x, y);
    }
    return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
}
```

The output is following, right after i create and insert item in scene, there was also moving the object around, but the method wasn't triggered:
[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLw88.png)

Comment: You don't set `ItemSendsGeometryChanges` flag on your custom item. `itemChange` gets `ItemPositionChange` notification only if that flag is set on true.

Comment: @rafix07 Thank you! your answer worked... Wondering if I'm not seeing things, or there isn't enough awareness about this flag when using this method, Either way Thank you very much!